# Closing a "local" OrientDB when using connection pools

Tags: local, connection-pooling, orientdb, file-storage

So I basically do this.

```
OObjectDatabaseTx result = OObjectDatabasePool.global().acquire( "local:orientdb", "admin", "admin");
//dostuff
result.close;
```

The problem is that when I redeploy my webapp (without restarting the Java EE container) I get the folling error:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage 'orientdb' with mode=rw
```

which I interpret to mean "Tomcat still has a filelock from the last app".

So my question is how do I cleanly exit in this scenario? I've tried:

```
OObjectDatabasePool.global().close()
```

and

```
new OObjectDatabaseTx("local:orientdb").close()
```

but neither seem to work. Any ideas? The documentation isn't exactly clear on this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the property "storage.keepOpen" to false:

```
java ... -Dstorage.keepOpen=false ...
```

or via Java code:

```
OGlobalConfiguration.STORAGE_KEEP_OPEN.setValue( false );
```

Comment: I wanted my program to move the database directory after using it, and found that in addition to closing the database and all storages (either by setting the property mentioned above or calling close(true) on every object in Orient.instance().getStorages()), I also had to call System.gc() for the file handles to actually be released before I could move the directory. I also called System.runFinalization() after the GC for good measure. I retry in a loop a few times with a sleep since there are no guarantees the GC will actually collect. I'm using OrientDB version 1.4.1 embedded in my process.

Comment: v1.4.1? That's pretty old. In recent versions we make available this new API: `Orient.instance.closeAllStorages()`

Comment: Yea, I haven't been able to upgrade yet for various reasons. How about an API to rename/move a database when closed? Would be nice to not have to call the Garbage Collector myself. I would need the API to work even when the database is totally corrupted or the folder is not really a database.

Comment: With 1.4.1 I don't remember what was supported, it's too old. I suggest you to upgrade to 2.1 and use that API.