# Can't open orientdb database from java application

Tags: java, sql, database, nosql, orientdb

When I use console everything works but when I try to open database from java application this errors appear

```
WARNING: Sun Unsafe direct  memory implementation is going to be used, this                    implementation is not stable so please use JNA version instead.
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.common.exception.OException: Error on creation of shared resource
at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OSharedContainerImpl.getResource(OSharedContainerImpl.java:55)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault.init(OMetadataDefault.java:110)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault.load(OMetadataDefault.java:68)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.open(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:132)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.open(ODatabaseWrapperAbstract.java:53)
at ru.sersem.bugsaccounting.RegBugs.openDataBase(RegBugs.java:36)
at com.library.test.Test.main(Test.java:5)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ORecordNotFoundException: The record with id '#0:1' not found
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.reload(ORecordAbstract.java:294)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.reload(ODocument.java:374)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.type.ODocumentWrapper.reload(ODocumentWrapper.java:87)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.type.ODocumentWrapperNoClass.reload(ODocumentWrapperNoClass.java:69)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared$16.call(OSchemaShared.java:605)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.OStorageAbstract.callInLock(OStorageAbstract.java:185)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.callInLock(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1322)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchemaShared.load(OSchemaShared.java:600)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault$1.call(OMetadataDefault.java:114)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.OMetadataDefault$1.call(OMetadataDefault.java:110)
at com.orientechnologies.common.concur.resource.OSharedContainerImpl.getResource(OSharedContainerImpl.java:53)
... 6 more
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on retrieving record #0:1 (cluster: internal)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.read(ODatabaseRaw.java:250)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordAbstract.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseRecordAbstract.java:706)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.loadRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:63)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.reload(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:232)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ODatabaseRecordTx.reload(ODatabaseRecordTx.java:38)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.ORecordAbstract.reload(ORecordAbstract.java:287)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/iq80/snappy/Snappy
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.compression.impl.OSnappyCompression.uncompress(OSnappyCompression.java:39)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OPaginatedCluster.readRecord(OPaginatedCluster.java:574)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.readRecord(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1160)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.paginated.OLocalPaginatedStorage.readRecord(OLocalPaginatedStorage.java:1140)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.read(ODatabaseRaw.java:244)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.iq80.snappy.Snappy
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 26 more
```

Should I configurate `orientdb-server-config.xml` or something else?
This is the code what I use to connect

```
public static void openDataBase() { 
    ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("plocal:/database/bugsac");
    db.open("admin", "admin");
    try {
        System.out.println(db.getName());
    } finally {
      db.close();
    }
```

The error occur here `db.open("admin", "admin");` The connection goes without errors. Could you suppose what is the problem?

Comment: Is that supposed to say "plocal:/database/bugsac" or instead "local:/database/bugsac" (without the 'p')?

Comment: If I use `local` instead `plocal` I Get `Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/database/bugsac' with mode=rw
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OStorageLocal.open(OStorageLocal.java:218) at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.raw.ODatabaseRaw.open(ODatabaseRaw.java:109) ...`

Comment: Ah, then take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383154/closing-a-local-orientdb-when-using-connection-pools

Comment: Now I still have this `Cannot open local storage '/database/bugsac' with mode=rw` and `Cannot open the storage 'bugsac' because it does not exist in path: /database/bugsac`

Comment: I wonder if you need to specify a "remote" connect instead. Take a look at this post: http://varraa.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/my-first-example-of-orientdb/ , otherwise, do you know for sure that path is correct?

Comment: When I use console.bat connection is successful but I always confuse this damn slashes. But anyway I sure that connection work until it reaches `db.open("admin", "admin");`

Comment: Is it possibly without the leading slash. Sorry, I'm just guessing here (I don't have a working system) so I'm just trying to be helpful. Maybe try this `"local:database/bugsac"`. I saw some examples online without the leading slash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.iq80.snappy.Snappy
```

Have you included snappy*.jar in your classpath?