# cannot connect remote oriendb after inserting data with JavaAPI

Tags: linux, database, orientdb, java

I know that there was questions about this theme, I found it in [Closing a "local" OrientDB when using connection pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383154/closing-a-local-orientdb-when-using-connection-pools). 
But it doesn't resolve my problem, which is: 
I have code

```
OrientGraphFactory ogf = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:/opt/orientdb/databases/sad", "admin", "admin");
    if(ogf.exists()){
        System.out.println("Database exist");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Database NOT exist");

    OrientGraph og = ogf.getTx();
    Vertex vPerson = og.addVertex("class:My");
    vPerson.setProperty("city", "Almaty");
    vPerson.setProperty("city", "Astana");
    System.out.println(og.countVertices());
    OGlobalConfiguration.STORAGE_KEEP_OPEN.setValue( false );
    og.shutdown();
    ogf.close();
```

After this when I'm trying connect via console.sh with command

```
connect remote:localhost/sad root root
```

it couldn't connect to databases with error:

```
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open local storage '/opt/orientdb/databases/sad' with mode=rw

Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException: Cannot load database's configuration. The database seems to be corrupted.
```

Also i added to orientdb-server-config.xml next 2 lines:

```
<properties>
        <entry value="1" name="db.pool.min"/>
        <entry value="50" name="db.pool.max"/>
        <entry value="true" name="profiler.enabled"/>
        <entry value="info" name="log.console.level"/>
        <entry value="fine" name="log.file.level"/>
        + <entry name="cache.size" value="10000" />
        + <entry name="storage.keepOpen" value="false" />
    </properties>
```

Please,help me.

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-8u91-b14-3ubuntu1~16.04.1-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

This is my java version

Comment: Which version of orientDb are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code with version 2.2.12, I changed only my path

```
OrientGraphFactory ogf = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:mypath/orientdb-community-2.2.12/databases/sad", "admin", "admin");
```

After I launched the server and from console I connected with the database.

[image]

Hope it helps.